# flutter custom design shape

Tags: flutter, widget, margin, shapes

i have this design(shown in the photo) which I want to code, I tried making the shape as an svg pic and put it in a container but I don't think that's the best way and also there is a margin on the sides that won't go even when I remove the padding(shown in the picture on the right)

my code is:

```
Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Align(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2),
                    child: buildLocalImage('assets/images/shape.svg'),
                  ),
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use custom paint. Check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are:

1. Clipping using `CustomClipper` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html)
2. Drawing using `CustomPainter` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)
3. Drawing using `RenderBox` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html)
4. Stacking clipped containers with `Stack` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)
5. Using images

It's unclear what the best option is because I am not sure what you will do after this is drawn (gesture detect, position, etc). But I would say option 2 is generally the most common.

Answer (score 0):

The margin propably stems from the SafeArea. Since you are in the body of a Scaffold, you probably do not need it there. Try to remove the SafeArea first, before you try sommething like a custom painter.

Also, you could use a package like [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) to embed the SVG shape into your app. This allows you to use the usual [fitting](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) parameters to position the shape.

To position the logo according to your mockup, you have to stack it over the SVG background. Use the [stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget for that.